# Setting cookies for the proxy urls

Tags: php, apache, web-applications, proxy, proxypass

I have a web application hosted in **address.domain.com**. As I cannot directly do a ajax request to **https://services.domain.com/**, I added the following proxy setting in my apache server config.

```
ProxyPass /my_proxy/ https://services.domain.com/
ProxyPassReverse /my_proxy/ https://services.domain.com/
```

Now when I do a ajax request to **https://address.domain.com/my_proxy/** it goes to **https://services.domain.com** from my server, which is what I want and I am able to do that. But the cookies which are set on the browser having the domain **services.domain.com** is not going along with the request **https://address.domain.com/my_proxy/**, as it is having a different domain. How to tackle this situation?

Comment: Maybe look at the directive ProxyPassReverseCookiePath or Domain ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain ) ... hope it could help

Comment: As far as I understood, this proxypassreversecookiepath or proxypassreversecookiedomain will help in setting the domain in set-cookie and this helps only when the services.domain.com request originates from my server. In my case, the proxy request originates from client side.

Comment: Your `ProxyPassReverse` does not match the `ProxyPass` site.  hint: you have an extra 'my.' in the reverse directive.  These must match.

Comment: I corrected that in the question. These are dummy urls given. My issue is a different one as I described in the question.